# Rails/React: Refs Must Have Owner

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I am using the react-rails gem. In my component I have two input fields with a ref each. However, the console throws me the following error:

> Uncaught Error: addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a ReactOwner can have
>   refs. You might be adding a ref to a component that was not created
>   inside a component's `render` method, or you have multiple copies of
>   React loaded

Facebook's documentation does not help.

**_new_item.js.jsx**

```
var NewItem = React.createClass({
    handleClick() {
        var name = this.refs.name.value;
        var description = this.refs.description.value;

       console.log('The name value is ' + name + 'the description value is ' + description);

    },

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input ref='name' placeholder='Enter the name of the item' />
                <input ref='description' placeholder='Enter a description' />
                <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Submit</button>
            </div>
        );
    } 
});
```

**_body.js.jsx**

```
var Body = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <NewItem />
                <AllItems />
            </div>
        );
    } 
});
```

**_main.js.jsx**

```
var Main = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header />
                <Body />
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

I really don't know where the error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll better use the function refs instead of the named refs:

So instead of

```
<input ref='name' />
```

You can use:

```
<input ref={node => this.nameElement = node} />
```

And then instead of:

```
this.refs.name
```

Use

```
this.nameElement
```

I believe it will fix your problem.